how to extract useragent complete (has spaces) from logfile
logfile line
4/10/2024--06:00pm guest 192.168.1.2 https://nixnut.nz/home/accounts/hosting.cgi?action=getonline Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:128.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/128.0

in logview file i have
open (FILE, "tail -$form{'howmany'} $file | tail -$form{'howmany'} |") or die "Opening $file: $!";

  while (<FILE>) {
    chomp;
    s/^\"//;
    s/\"$//;
    my ($date, $user, $host, $page, $browser) = split(' ', $_);
print "<tr bgcolor=black>";
print "<td bgcolor=white align=left valign=top>$font $date</td>";
print "<td bgcolor=white align=left valign=top><a href=http://nixnut.nz/$user target=_blank>$font $user</a></td>";
print "<td bgcolor=white align=left valign=top>$font <a href=https://www.iptolocation.io/ip-lookup/$host target=_blank>$host</a></td>";
print "<td bgcolor=white align=left valign=top>$font <a href=http://$host target=_blank>$host</a></td>";
print "<td bgcolor=white align=left valign=top><a href=$page target=_blank>$font $page</a></td>";
print "<td bgcolor=white align=left valign=top>$font $browser</td>";
print "</tr>\n";
  }
  close (FILE);

the output is
4/10/2024--06:00pm  guest   192.168.1.2 192.168.1.2 https://nixnut.nz/home/accounts/hosting.cgi?action=getonline    Mozilla/5.0

missing the full useragent due to spaces
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:128.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/128.0       


Why the double-tail  in tail -$form{'howmany'} $file | tail -$form{'howmany'}? BTW, I hope you sanitize/shell-quote those $form{howmany} / $file or you have an ACE vulnerability. Using the safe form of open rather than that one using a shell would have mitigated the issue as in open FILE, '-|', 'tail', '-n', $form{howmany}, '--', $file; you should also HTML escape the values you output.

i changed the 2nd howmany to seconds (which is the other file to read) and it still worked. i replaced that line with yours and it works the same. the files in question contain seconds to refresh (2 to 3 or so numbes) and how many log lines to display with same amount of numbers so not not sure what the security issue is

Add the LIMIT argument to the split() call.  You have five variables for fields, so the LIMIT is 5:
my ($date, $user, $host, $page, $browser) = split(' ', $_, 5);

The first four space-delimited fields will go into $date, $user, $host, and $page, as they have been.  $browser will receive the rest of the line instead of just the part before the next space character.
See the Perldoc page for split() for the full details and examples.

that works, thank you so much

@nixnut would you be willing to mark the answer as accepted?  IIRC, it's the checkmark just to the left of the text of the answer.

yes definately and thanks for answering so fast, much appreciated :)

Go find whoever configured the webserver and tell them to fix it. Seriously. There are standard formats for log files ("combined", originally from Apache, is probably the most useful) which are designed to be machine readable. You will constantly be reinventing the same processes / unable to use off-the-shelf tools for monitoring / reporting otherwise.

these are not webserver logs and the tracking script uses only it's own script to generate and read them within a users public directoy

"these are not webserver logs" - really? Last time I checked Firefox was a web browser. While browsers will connect using other protocols (e.g. FTP) those other protocols do not present a user-agent. Perhaps you could tell us what it is then?

wow, this has nothing to do with apache logs, it's a perl script that generates logs in the user public_html (as i have already said), this is a snippet from the script that produces the logs > $browser = "$ENV{'HTTP_USER_AGENT'}";
open (LOGFILE, ">>$logfile") or die ">>$logfile: $!";
print LOGFILE "$date $user $host $page $browser\n";

Its a webserver log.
